# tcptrace from wireshark 802.11 capture

Tags: wireshark

I have the same question Lukas asked on April 1...
How can I use tcptrace to generate tcptrace graph from captures on Wireshark?  Guy responded by asking if just feeding the Wireshark output to tcptrace worked, but I didn't see any followup.  My physical type is IEEE802_11_RADIO.  I started by feeding the Wireshark output to tcptrace, but I got a segfault.  I exported the file as (Wireshark/tcpdump) pcap rather than pcapng, filtered the output to TCP traffic only (still 802.11 frames though), and truncated the file to only the stream of interest, but tcptrace rejects all of the packets as not being IP ("pread_tcpdump: not an IP packet").

Comment: Who's Lukas, and what question are you speaking of?

Comment: On Apr 1, Lukas Irides posted a very similar question with the title, "tcptrace from wireshark capture".

Answer (score 0):

> My physical type is IEEE802_11_RADIO.

Then you're screwed, because the current version of tcptrace doesn't handle DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO correctly - it assumes that the radiotap header is 64 bytes long, rather than looking at the length field of the radiotap header to see how long the header *actually* is.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it might be something like that when I saw the constants in the offset calculation.  Did the radiotap header change when VHT support was added?  It doesn't look like tcptrace has been kept up to date...

Comment: The radiotap header was *never* specified as 64 bytes long, and there is *no* guarantee that it will be 64 bytes for *any* PHY type.  Which particular fields are provided is up to the driver.  All VHT support did was add a new field, which would be present for VHT frames, just as HT support added the MCS and A-MPDU status fields, the latter of which could also be used for VHT frames.

Comment: Sadly, it appears that tcptrace isn't being maintained very much any more; an [associate dean and associate professor](https://www.ohio.edu/engineering/about/profiles.cfm?profile=0BD3F42C-5056-A800-486D3E1266AA906B) might not have time for it any more.  I couldn't find anybody who's officially taken it over.